# geom_smooth gives different fit than nls alone

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

Because I wanted to have the nls model separately, I did a fit to my data inside the geom_smooth function and outside ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
a <- 4
b <- -2
data$y <- with(data, exp(a + b * x) + rnorm(100) + 100)
mod <- nls(formula = y ~ (exp(a + b * x)), data = data, start = list(a = a, b = b))
data$fit <- predict(mod, newdata=data)

plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "nls", colour = "red", formula=y ~ exp(a + b * x),
                method.args = list(start = c(a = a, b = b)), se=F, span=0) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=x, y=fit), colour="blue") +
    scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

I just wondering why both methods, though with the same parameters, give a different fit? Does geom_smooth use some transformation?

Comment: Is it because of the scales? If you remove the +scale_y_log10(), the lines look more similar.

Comment: Sure, but the result is still not equal, though the input is the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`geom_smooth` doesn't make predictions from the original dataset, but instead makes a dataset for prediction.  By default this dataset has 80 rows, but you can change this with the `n` argument.

To see that the model fit via `geom_smooth` and the model fit by `nls` are the same, you need to use the same dataset for prediction.  You can pull the one used by `geom_smooth` out via `ggplot_build`.  The dataset used for prediction is the second in the list.

```
dat2 = ggplot_build(plot)$data[[2]]
```

Now use `dat2` for making predictions from the nls model and remake the plot.

```
dat2$fit2 = predict(mod, newdata = dat2)

ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "nls", colour = "red", formula=y ~ exp(a + b * x),
              method.args = list(start = c(a = 4, b = -2)), se = FALSE) + 
    geom_line(data = dat2, aes(x=x, y=fit2), colour="blue")
```

[image]

Note that if you want to display on the log10 scale when comparing `geom_smooth` to a predicted line you'll want to use `coord_trans(y = "log10")` instead of `scale_y_log10`.  Scale transformation happens *prior to* model fitting, so you would be fitting a model to a log10-transformed y if you use `scale_y_log10`.

Comment: Just the difference between `coord_trans` and `scale_y_log10` makes the difference. Thx.